# Get svn username as maven property

Tags: svn, properties, maven

Is there a way to have svn user name used to checkout a project visible as a maven property ? Something like `scm.svn.username` ? If not, what solutions can you imagine to let me get that property ?

The ultimate goal is to use svn username for [some resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).

**EDIT** Seems like [maven-scm plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/plugins/index.html) provides an [ScmManager](http://maven.apache.org/scm/guide/usage.html) object. Can I use it in my POM ? Or maybe in [some groovy code](http://www.ronniealleva.org/index.php/2008/01/23/using-the-groovy-maven-plugin-to-do-magic/) I could write ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be to add a user name property into a settings.xml

An alternative would be to build a custom Maven plugin to read svn user name from a local svn configuration, or extend an existing one to support such feature, e.g. look at [buildnumber-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/).